Integrability condition of composite function in Jensen's inequality
In Jensen's inequality $\phi(\mathbb{E}[X])\leq \mathbb{E}[\phi(X)]$,
it is required that $\phi(X)$ is integrable. But why? If this integral is infinity, the inequality is still correct.

There is no guarantee that $E[\phi (X)]$ exists (finite or not).

@geetha290krm Thanks for your comment! What exactly do you mean by existence here? How I know this term in measure theory is that it says an integral exists if it is finite.

If $EY^{+}=\infty=EY^{-}$ then you just cannot write $EY$. It has no meaning.

If $X$ is integrable, then $E[\phi(X)]$ does exists in the sense that it is either $\phi(X)$ is integrable, or $E[\phi(X)]=\infty$. This is because $E[\phi(X)_-]<\infty$.
